# Online Python Interpreter

Tags: python, web, interpreter

The new [Python](https://www.python.org/) website and [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) have online Python interpreters. The interpreter in the Python website has been designed by Python anywhere.

**Question:** How do I design an online interpreter for Python? No, I don't need the code or anything I just need the name of the tools/APIs that can be used for this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what a "toll" is in this context. Are you asking for the core APIs you would need to build an online REPL?

You can have a look at the source code of [repl.it](http://repl.it/languages/Python) at [github](https://github.com/holdenk/repl.it).

Comment: Sorry, sorry, edited it.

Comment: There's no standard way to do this. You might also look at http://jslinux.org/ which uses this javascript-DOM terminal emulator: http://jslinux.org/term.js to get an idea of what's involved.